# Limiting database access within Quicksight

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services

We have 100 source client databases all with the same schema. We would like to stream this data into Kafka using Debezium and Sql Server. We want to continue to maintain data separation with the data when it is brought into Postgres and Quicksight. So we need a firewall mechanism to prevent data for a client being viewed by other clients when it is viewed in Quicksight.

What ways can you manage the safety of topics in Kafka and into Postgres so we can continue to keep data private to a client, but still perform cross client queries for some use cases.

eg. If we have a source Sales table which does not have a client code in.
We want to present sales data analytics to clients via a Quicksight Portal.
And also a Sales manager that wants to see sales analytics across all Clients.

Comment: Removing Kafka tag since the location of the original data is an implementation detail. Database queries can be limited by user accounts. Can Quicksight be limited by IAM access? You could also use Presto/Trino (maybe Athena), or Dremio to do cross-queries from several databases which would be separated by client...

Comment: Actually this is Kafka related. I just saw you can do row level security in Quicksight on Client code for instance. Its more a kafka question, how we would populate that client code in a topic for a sales table which does not have client in. The client code comes from a different table. Do we create sales and client topics for each client (100 x 2 topics) and then merge them in an ETL step ? Or is there a better way?

Comment: I will look at presto/trino thanks.

Comment: Thanks, I see your point. Kafka/debezium may not be the implementation tool for the job. Presto seems a far better tool and is open source.